# What is the meaning of "Target Range" in the Azure Scale Profile portal blade?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, autoscaling, azureportal

In the new Azure portal under
Cloud services > Scaling blade > Scale Profile > choosing Recurrence
There is a range of instances to choose, if I understood correctly.

Can someone explain the meaning of a "range", since in  certain hour I would expect to have a fixed number of instances.

[New portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRzXV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **range** defines the minimum and maximum number of instances that will be running at any given time. For example, if you're configuring a scale profile based on CPU load you will have CPU percentage rules in place that will add/remove instances based on CPU thresholds you define. The scale profile will add/remove instances as needed **within the range you specified**.

Answer (score 1):

The Range in the new Portal has 2 sliders Minimum and Max Number of Instances

Depending on the trigger you will set for this to Happen

1. Manual Scale : The Nummber of Instances will be set based on your Choice
2. CPU : You set the Minimum and the Max for Instances and Besed on the CPU Untalization Azure will Set the Number of instances
3. Other Measures : Same as CPU but for Queuing, Traffic, Disk I/O Etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is "Scale Profile" and also a sub scaling call "rule".

The rule determine the scale within the range of the "Scale Profile".

Answer (score 0):

target range for the metric. For example, if you chose CPU percentage, you can set a target for the average CPU across all of the instances in your service. A scale out will happen when the average CPU exceeds the maximum you define, likewise, a scale in will happen whenever the average CPU drops below the minimum

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale